# Modify IList Query Statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, linq-to-sql

I have the following statement, and I want to modify it to not select all tables.

1. Exclude 2 columns `customerItemNo` and `manufacturerItemNo` in the `if`, and
2. Exclude 2 columns `customerItemNoAppend` and `manufacturerItemNoAppend` in the `else if`.

How can I do it?

```
if (p.UserInternal == 'Y' && p.UserActive == 'Y')
    inventorySummary = DataProvider.SelectCondition<Q_TBL_INVENTORY_SUMMARY>
(r => r.InventoryLocationNo == location);

else if (p.UserInternal != 'Y' && p.UserActive == 'Y')
    inventorySummary = DataProvider.SelectCondition<Q_TBL_INVENTORY_SUMMARY>
(r => r.InventoryLocationNo == location && (r.CustomerID == customerID || r.CustomerID == " "));

else
    inventorySummary = new List<Q_TBL_INVENTORY_SUMMARY>();
```

Comment: What does "exclude two columns" mean?

Comment: Can you please add the model of Q_TBL_INVENTORY_SUMMARY and input data